# Browserstack.com webtunnel not working

Tags: php, apache, hosts, lampp, browserstack

I'm using Browserstack.com local test and it seems not working for me.
I installed lampp on my Ubuntu 12.04 and configured `httpd-vhosts.conf` and `/etc/hosts` like below:
`httpd-vhosts.conf:`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/ME/FOLDER"
    ServerName  dev
</VirtualHost>
```

---

`/etc/hosts:`

```
127.0.0.1  dev
```

I can access my PHP site on my local machine by typing `dev/` in Chrome, but when using Browserstack's web tunnel for local test, it won't work after I input `dev` as HOST and `80` as PORT.
Does anyone know how to make things work? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

BrowserStack's web applet doesn't works with openjdk+icedtea-6-plugin combination. Is it possible for you to switch to sun/oracle java[1]?

[1] https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk

Comment: Sadly I can't decide whether to switch to sun java...Since command line mode works for me now, I think I'll stay with openjdk now. Thanks for the official explanation, not confused anymore!

Answer (score 1):

well, just tried command line mode and it works. Following the official documentation, type this command `java -jar BrowserStackTunnel.jar <MYKEY> dev,80,0`, the dashboard page will prompt you it's OK to run local site automatically.

Perhaps a bug with web tunnel? I'm using open_jdk 1.6 and I installed icedtea-6-plugin for Chrome, don't know if it has anything to do with the version.

Anyway, command line is totally OK but I wonder if someone can help configure the web tunnel with me.